# How to send invitation to gtalk contact with smack java library?

Tags: java, xmpp, smack, google-talk

How to send invitation to gtalk contact with smack java library?

Comment: This question is pretty open-ended.  What are some of the things you've tried?  What problems are you having?  When you don't include these details, it's difficult to know what kind of an answer you're looking for.  Unless, that is, you're looking for someone to do all the work for you...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//Setting up connection
ConnectionConfiguration config = new ConnectionConfiguration("talk.google.com", 5222, "gmail.com");
        connection = new XMPPConnection(config);
        connection.connect();
//login
        connection.login(userName, password);
//get your roster   
    Roster roster = connection.getRoster();
//add a new roster entry aka SEND INVITATION

roster.createEntry(address, name, groups);
```

For further details look this page:
http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/3.1.0/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/Roster.html

Answer (score 0):

Using the code below, you can construct the contact with gtalk.

```
ConnectionConfiguration conf = new ConnectionConfiguration(  
        "talk.google.com",  
        5222,  
        "gmail.com");  
conf.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(false);
XMPPConnection con = new XMPPConnection(conf);  
con.connect();  
/* 
 * username : username@gmail.com

 * password : 
 */  
con.login("username", "password");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve Gtalk contact as follows:

```
GoogleTalkConnection con = new GoogleTalkConnection();
con.login(”joesmith”, “password”);
con.createChat(”maryjane@gmail.com”).sendMessage(”Howdy!”);
con.close();
```